# Facebook Channel support (Beta) doesn't allow quick replies, buttons, media, etc

Tags: facebook, twilio, twilio-api

Does anybody know if there's any way of using standard Facebook Messenger features like quick replies, buttons or templates from Facebook Channel (Beta) via Programmable API?

As it is right now it seems too limited to be of any use beyond simple text conversations; no prefilled answers, no links to actions or products...

Are there any (short term) plans to support it? (just being able to send a json like in Facebook own API would be more than enough https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/buttons/quick-replies)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, you are right that the integration is relatively simple.

What you want to look out for is the [Twilio Messaging Content API](https://www.twilio.com/go/messaging-content-api-request-access-1) which is currently in pilot. The Content API is intended to make rich messaging across any of the channels that Twilio offers easier. The Content API will wrap each of the channels, making it straightforward to add buttons, actions or prefills to messages over channels that support it, with fallbacks for simpler channels (like our old friend SMS). The API is in pilot right now, but you can [register your interest and request access here](https://www.twilio.com/go/messaging-content-api-request-access-1).